# check value of a specific element in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

i used if else to check if the element at index i,i of a numpy matrix is 0

```
if a[i, i]==0:
```

got the error
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: This error is not from the line you showed. Provide more code

Comment: ```if any(a[i, i]==0)``` your ```a[i,i]``` Has apparently more than 1 dimension

Comment: what's the sbape and dtype of  `a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `a[i, i]` is not a single value rather a list or numpy array. And you can't check with just one `if condition` all values in a list/numpy array.
What you could do is:

```py
for item in a.flatten():
    if item == =.
       # do sth
```